# Apply active class to current url is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, gsp

I have a sidebar nav bar in my project and I have to apply the `class="active"` to every `href` link dynamically I applied so many jquery/javasctipt function to it but its not working and its a Groovy server page(gsp).
[image: My url Links]

So far what I tried

```
var activeurl = window.location;
$('#nav a[href="'+activeurl+'"]').parent('li').addClass('active');
```

2nd one

```
$(function(){

var url = window.location.pathname, 
    urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case trailing slash wasn't present there
    // now grab every link from the navigation
    $('#nav a').each(function(){
        // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
        if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

3rd one

```
$("#nav a").each(function() {   
if (this.href == window.location.href) {
    $(this).addClass("active");
   }
});
```

Comment: Debug time: console.log `this.href` and `window.location.href` to see what's going on.

Comment: yes request is coming to browser console and alert also displaying .

Comment: `window.location.href` is showing the links but `this.href` is showing undefined.

Comment: Alert? What I meant was log to the console what the variables are in the 3rd example.

Comment: yes i tested in 3 ex one alert means that i am checking the request is coming into script or not

Comment: if `this.href` is undefined you have big problems in the html

Comment: Yes Thanks I got This